# Rendering Chief Architect files

Tags: rendering

Chief Architect Premier is my primary modeling software. It's very comprehensive and the rendering is quite good but not up to the level I've seen from Blender. Can anyone direct me to a tutorial on how to render Chief Architect files in Blender?

Comment: These are two completely different programs, you cannot render the file of CAF in blender just like that. You have to export the whole scene to eg. obj, fbx, dae files, then create new materials in blender with a compatible render engine, eg cycles/Eevee, octane, luxCore, renderman. And then render it out. You can find plenty of tutorials on that on YouTube

Comment: Much as I thought, I assume that I will need to import a completed 3d model (I should have been more clear in my original post). I'm looking for a clear tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: Export from CAP, then in blender file>import>fbx then select your file. So what you have to search for is how you export from CAP, just type it in youtube. And how to import in blender

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.